# no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const Vehicle' and 'const Vehicle')

Tags: c++, class, c++17

I have this class:

```
class Vehicle {
    private:
        char dir_;
    public:
        char car_;
        // functions
        // 
        // overloaded operators
        bool operator==(Vehicle&);
        bool operator<(const Vehicle& v);
        //
        // other functions
    
};
```

which has this implementation:

```
bool Vehicle::operator<(const Vehicle& v) {
    return (car_ < v.car_);
}
```

And I'm getting this error:
"no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const Vehicle' and 'const Vehicle')"

which is in "stl_funxtion.h"

Comment: You need to declare `operator<` const

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. No clue how you get the error in "stl_function.h".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a function usable on a `const` object, you need to declare that function `const`:

```cpp
class Vehicle {
      ⋮
    bool operator<(const Vehicle& v) const;
      ⋮                              ^^^^^
      ⋮
};

bool Vehicle::operator<(const Vehicle& v) const {
      ⋮                                   ^^^^^
}
```